# How do I trap errors in the Twilio library in the browser?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm using the Twilio Video SDK to build a video chat site.  The core functionality is working, but I keep seeing sporadic errors in the browser console, like these:

```
- (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
- ICE Connection Monitor detected inactivity
- An ICE restart has been scheduled
- Attempting to restart ICE
- ICE failed, add a STUN server and see about:webrtc for more details
```

Some appear to be warnings, some are errors.  How do I trap those errors so I can update the UI appropriately?  I think I would want to use the EventEmitter logic here: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.5.1/docs/global.html#EventListener__anchor

My questions:

- Is this the right approach?
- If so, how do I implement that in browser-side javascript, specifically the "require('events')" piece?
- Why can't I find good Twilio documentation online?  I know it's out there somewhere, but I keep having to trial-and-error my way through the code, or open support tickets, which is slow and not fair to the support team.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt I'm the only one confused by this, so here's what I have been able to figure out (hopefully this helps someone else).  Here is my heavily redacted code:

```
Twilio.Video.connect(token, { 
    options
}).then(room => {
    room.on('reconnecting', error => {console.log("Room reconnecting: " + error );});
}, error => {
    console.log('Unable to connect to Room: ' + error.message);
});
```

According to the docs: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.6.0/docs/Room.html, the room class extends EventEmitter, so you don't need to create a separate EventEmitter object, and the "require('events');" pieces is not needed.    The docs also list the events that you can listen for, although there seem to be some gaps.  For example, the Participant class emits the 'trackSubscribed' event, but it's not in the documentation.

For the errors that I'm seeing, it appears that the Room 'reconnecting' event is what I need to pay attention to.  If it's successful, it emits the 'reconnected' event, so I need to see if I get one and not the other, which would indicate a problem that I might need to manually address.

Comment: I am facing the same issues in my console. Could you help me with the approach you took to fix these?