# Twilio Video and Audio stops working after a while during Programmable Video call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-video

During an hour long video call, audio stops working after sometime (~40 minutes breakpoint) without showing any error in the console. How to catch these issues and fix these?

Also, one of the person on the call can hear other but it is not going the other way around. Could someone help to debug these kind of issues?

Here are some of the screenshots I was able to take at 50 minutes breakpoint during one of the calls:

[image]

PS: We are on an upgraded plan.

Comment: In one of the call, neither of the 2 participants could see or hear each other. Also, reconnecting also didn't help

Comment: Some of the other errors I see in console are related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616015/how-do-i-trap-errors-in-the-twilio-library-in-the-browser/62647410#62647410

Comment: While it doesn't help with audio disconnecting during the call, have you tried the [Twilio Video diagnostics](https://github.com/twilio/rtc-diagnostics) which allows you to test audio, video and bandwidth before joining a room? Related to the question you linked, are you listening for the "reconnecting" event?

Comment: Yes, we did check https://networktest.twilio.com/ and it showed all the tests being passed. Issue is, after a certain time has lapsed in the call, both the users starts facing issues with Audio and Video. Happening pretty frequently.

Regarding "reconnecting" event, no we are not listening to it. What should we do in case we get "reconnecting" event during a call?

Comment: If you get the "reconnecting" event during the call it's best to show the users that one of the participants has dropped briefly but should be back soon. I think for the audio dropping out issues it's likely best to contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide some Room SIDs where this happened and they will be able to inspect the logs to see if something happened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way for me to test it in local (reconnecting event) instead of waiting for it to be triggered by Twilio?

Comment: You could try to simulate a connection loss with browser dev tools? I’ve not tried it, but that might trigger this action.